# Whenever i load my gameScene from my menu the size is way to big

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scene

im pretty new to swift and i literally cant figure this out anywhere. When i load the game with out the menuScene it loads perfectly all assets and everything but the moment that i launch with menuScene it doesn't scale properly. Thanks in advance any help appreciated.

`override func   touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let gameScene = GameScene()
        view!.presentScene(gameScene)
        scene?.scaleMode = .aspectFill`

is it something in the gameScene i need to change?

Comment: It's hard to help you without any images. However, try to add a SKCameraNode

Comment: That worked! now im just having an issue of my sprite that i set up in the SKS file not appearing on screen. Thank you though! one issue down one to go!

Answer (score 0):

I took Simones answer and I thought it had worked but it just moved the screen but i still had the issue of my sprites not being resized I ended up adding the same code in the if let view from gameview controller to my touches began. This worked exactly how I wanted it to.

```
 override func   touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let view = self.view {

        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
            view.presentScene(scene)
```

Comment: yes, if you look at the code, your GameScene is loading a file, which defines your size.  You are also setting the scale mode of the new scene, not the potentially old scene (I have no idea what scene?.scalemode will do after you present the new scene.  I would think it would be either nil or self, not the new scene)